# Quickly can't package, but raises no errors

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, packaging, pygi

I am trying to make a .deb package for my project in quickly. This is what I get:

```
ilya@ilya-laptop:~/Projects/online-translator$ quickly package
...........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
..........................................................
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
ERROR: xgettext failed to generate PO template file. Please consult
       error message above if there is any.
----------------------------------
Произошла ошибка во время сборки пакета.
ОШИБКА: Не удалось выполнить команду package
Прервано
```

The last lines in Russian do not mean anything, except for telling, that there was an error, while packaging.

> Please consult error message above if there is any.

And what to do, if there is no messages?..

**EDIT:**

OK, I found, that you can run quickly package with --verbose option, so this is the error part:

```
intltool-update -p -g online-translator
xgettext: ошибка открытия файла "./../yandex_translate/__init__.py" для чтения: Нет такого файла или каталога
### It says, it can't use file "./../yandex_translate/__init__.py", because there is no such file
ERROR: xgettext failed to generate PO template file. Please consult
       error message above if there is any.
error: command 'intltool-update' failed with exit status 1
dh_auto_build: python setup.py build --force returned exit code 1
make: *** [build] Ошибка 1
dpkg-buildpackage: ошибка: debian/rules build возвратил код ошибки 2
Произошла ошибка во время сборки пакета.
ОШИБКА: Не удалось выполнить команду package
Прервано
```

I use yandex_translate module in my app, but why should xgettext use it's files? Where can there be a reference to that file? There is truly no such file there, because I have already removed the module directory from my project folder, but it was there before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the file `project/po/POTFILES.in`. When I removed all references to the files, which the Quickly package couldn't find, which can be seen with

```
quickly package --verbose
```

it worked like a charm.